# Proper use of the cin object?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am using Microsoft visual studio to build a simple windows console application that exhibits simple I/O. When I input more than one word to be assigned to a string variable using the cin object, the program automatically displays all of my following questions immediately. What can I do to allow for multiple word inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For situations when you need a string that allows spaces, use `std::getline` in place of the `>>` operator:

```
std::string withSpaces;
getline(cin, withSpaces);
```

Comment: getline by the way returns the istream object i.e. cin in this case...so if u write something like while(cin>>string) u can replace that with while(getline(cin, string)) and the meaning would be retained...and u wud also have the advantage of reading an entire line instead of a word as dasblinkenlight already mentioned